# Problem fetching the ros_controller state from controller/state topic

Tags: ros, ros-control, gazebo-ros, roscpp, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS-Indigo on Ubunu 14.04. While using MoveIt! with ros-controllers I wanted to capture the data published on
coro/coro_arm_controller/state topic. However while the acceleration and effort fields, segmentation fault error is coming.
Below is my code.  Can anyone  suggest me on what to do next ??

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <control_msgs/JointTrajectoryControllerState.h>
#include <trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


void callback(const control_msgs::JointTrajectoryControllerState& traj)
{ trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint desired, actual, error_;
  ros::Duration t; 
 actual.accelerations.resize(7);
 actual.effort.resize(7);
  for(int j=0; j<traj.joint_names.size();++j)
  { 
      // Desired
      desired.positions.push_back(traj.desired.positions[j]);
      desired.velocities.push_back(traj.desired.velocities[j]);
      desired.accelerations.push_back(traj.desired.accelerations[j]);
      desired.effort.push_back(traj.desired.accelerations[j]);

      actual.positions.push_back(traj.actual.positions[j]);
      actual.velocities.push_back(traj.actual.velocities[j]);
      //actual.accelerations.push_back(traj.actual.accelerations[j]);
      //actual.effort.push_back(traj.actual.accelerations[j]);

     error_.positions.push_back(traj.error.positions[j]);
     error_.velocities.push_back(traj.error.velocities[j]);
     //error_.accelerations.push_back(traj.error.accelerations[j]);
    //   error_.effort.push_back(traj.error.effort[j]);
  }
    
     for(int i= 0; i< traj.joint_names.size();++i) 
 {
  ROS_INFO_STREAM( "position  for joint["<< i << "] :"  << desired.positions[i]);
  ROS_INFO_STREAM( "velocity  for joint["<< i << "] :"  << desired.velocities[i]);
  ROS_INFO_STREAM( "acceleration  for joint["<< i << "] :"  << desired.accelerations[i]);
  ROS_INFO_STREAM( "effort for joint["<< i << "] :"  << desired.effort[i]);
 }
  ROS_INFO_STREAM( "time is :"  << t << "\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ros::init (argc, argv, "trajectory");
   ros::NodeHandle n;
   
   ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/zuti_bot/zuti_bot_arm_controller/state", 1000, callback);
   while(ros::ok())
   {
     ros::spinOnce();
   }
      
   
    return 0;

}
```

After many iterations I found that there  is  some problem while capturing the acceleration and effort value of the joints.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286312/problem-fetching-the-ros_controller-state-from-controller/state-topic/) by [Pulkit123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28301/pulkit123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2018-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you made sure the `accelerations` and `efforts` fields are actually populated?

Note in the documentation for [trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint](http://docs.ros.org/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectoryPoint.html):

> ```
> # Each trajectory point specifies either positions[, velocities[, accelerations]]
> ```

```
# or positions[, effort] for the trajectory to be executed.
```

The `[]` in `[, velocities[, accelerations]]` and `[, effort]` indicate that these are optional. Not all implementations may populate those fields.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pulkit123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28301/pulkit123/) on 2018-03-23**:
Actually I am giving trajectory through MoveIt! and capturing the controller_state data. I checked using **rostopic echo**  and found that the acceleration and effort fields are not populated by default for actual and error parts. So how to rectify this ??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-23**:
I would suggest to check that (for instance) `actual.efforts.size() > 0`.

**Comment by [Pulkit123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28301/pulkit123/) on 2018-03-23**:
I checked it, actually the acceleration ad effort fields of actual and error parts   of control_msgs::JointTrajectoryControllerState are never been filled by default. That's why it is giving segmentation fault. However only the effort field of desired part is not populated by default.